# Casio fx-9750GII calculator file transfer

Tags: usb, calculator

I've got a Casio fx-9750GII calculator, which has a USB connection. When I connect it to my computer the system does not mount it as a storage device. When I run `lsusb` this is the output:

```
root@akerbeltz:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0ac8:c335 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 07cf:6101 Casio Computer Co., Ltd
```

My question is: Is it possible to transfer programs (.g1m) to the calculator as is done in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casio provide an application called FA-124 that can be used to transfer files from a Windows computer to a 9860GII or 9750GII (or similar). You could try running this in WINE but this of course isn't an ideal solution since it's not a native application.

Alternatively, there's a project written by Andreas Bertheussen called [xfer9860](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xfer9860/). I found this didn't work out of the box with my CASIO fx-9860GII calculator - my understanding is that CASIO changed how the communication protocol worked with the "GII" calculators which causes the xfer9860 utility to not work with the newer calculator models since it was designed for a fx-9860G model.

I searched around and found some forum posts with information on what parts of the code needed changing. After modifying the code given in the forum posts I was able to get the project to compile and transferring files in both directions worked without any issues.

I have a fork of the original project on GitHub which includes the [patch](https://github.com/lol768/xfer9860/commit/5b3d3abb818a896b4eca9f90b404a8f7df0bbba3)
I talked about above. Whilst I've only tested this with a 9860GII calculator, I'm optimistic it will work with a 9750GII as long as you're not trying to transfer G1A files (add-in applications), since the 9750GII's software doesn't support running user-supplied add-in applications.

It's worth noting you can upgrade the 9750GII's firmware to the 9860GII's in some cases since the 9750 is essentially a 9860 with dumbed-down software and a lower price point (though this will void the warranty) so this might be a good idea if you don't have any luck at first with the transfer application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been very useful for me. I previusly upgraded my firmware to 9860GII's, so now I can transfer G1A files. Thank you again